# Calling two functions that use different database using sqlite3 in C

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm developing C Application that displays History fi chrome and Firefox (using Sqlite3) .

> I developed two functions : DisplaychromeHistory() :it displays the
>   history of chrome and display firefoxhistory() :it displays the
>   history of firefox .
>   The Problem that the two functions works well but when I call them in main only the first function works : Exemple if my program feels like :

```
int main()
{
    DisplayFirefoxHistory();
    DisplayChromeHistory();

    return 0;
}
```

then only DisplayFirefoxHistory(); works but if my code seems like

```
int main()
{
    DisplayChromeHistory();
    DisplayFirefoxHistory();

    return 0;
}
```

Only display chrome works : The program doesn't show any error . I think about clear the cache but it doesn't change anything

```
int main()
{
    DisplayFirefoxHistory();
    DisplayChromeHistory();

    return 0;
}
int DisplayChromeHistory()
{

    char  pathFileh[] = "c:/Users//AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/History";
    char username[UNLEN+1];
    DWORD username_len = UNLEN+1;
    GetUserName(username, &username_len);
    insert_substring(pathFileh,username,10);
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *err_msg = 0;
    if (chrome_is_running2())
        system("taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F");
    int rc = sqlite3_open(pathFileh, &db);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);

        return 1;
    }

    char *sql = "select datetime(last_visit_time/1000000-11644473600,'unixepoch'),url from  urls order by last_visit_time desc";

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, NULL, &err_msg);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK ) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to select data\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);

        sqlite3_free(err_msg);
        sqlite3_close(db);
        sqlite3_db_cacheflush(db);

        return 1;
    }

    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}

int DisplayFirefoxHistory()
{
    char  pathFileh[] = "C:/Users/ ****/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/dbi1yjvy.default/places.sqlite";
    char username[UNLEN+1];

    sqlite3 *dbF;
    char *err_msg = 0;

    Sleep(1000);

    int rc = sqlite3_open(pathFileh, &dbF);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n",sqlite3_errmsg(dbF));
        sqlite3_close(dbF);
        return 1;
    }
    char *sql = "select url,datetime(visit_date/1000000-11644473600,'unixepoch') from  moz_historyvisits , moz_places order by visit_date desc";
    rc = sqlite3_exec(dbF, sql, callbackFirefox, NULL, &err_msg);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK ) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to select data\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);

        sqlite3_free(err_msg);
        sqlite3_close(dbF);

        return 1;
    }
    sqlite3_close(dbF);
    return 0;
}

int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv,
                    char **azColName) {

    char  pathFileRe[] = "c:/ResulatEpreuve/Exploit.txt";
    FILE *fp ;
    fp=fopen(pathFileRe,"a");
    fprintf(fp,"%s = %s\n", argv[0], argv[1] );
    return 0;
}

int callbackFirefox(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv,
                    char **azColName) {
    char  pathFileRe[] = "c:/ResulatEpreuve/Exploit2.txt";
    FILE *fp ;
    fp=fopen(pathFileRe,"a");
    fprintf(fp,"%s = %s\n", argv[0], argv[1] );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `insert_substring` do? When you call it like `insert_substring(pathFileh,username,10)` does it modify `pathFileh`? More specifically does it try to *add* characters to `pathFileh`? Because that's problematic since `pathFileh` have a fixed size and "adding" characters to it will cause you to write out of bounds and that will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Ye insert substring will add username in the postion 10 and the the path will be like c:/Users/(Exemple)Alex/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/History .

Comment: Then that's your most likely culprit. The `pathFileh` array only have space enough for the string you initialize it with (including terminator) and nothing more. Writing out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior* which makes your whole program *ill-formed* and invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in function Callback and callbackFirefox I have to close File .When i add

```
fclose (fp);
```

It works well .